# How to concat two Strings and search for record

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a search page where I give user 3 options to search for customer record.
User can search either by Customer Id,First Name or Last Name.

HTML CODE:

```html
 <div class="row" *ngIf="indCust">
      <!-- Search Records by Id -->
      <div class="text-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Id" [(ngModel)]="customerIdValue" />
        <label (click)="searchByCustomerIdGraph()">Search</label>
      </div>

      <!-- Search Record by Individual Customer First Name -->
      <div class="text-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Customer First Name" [(ngModel)]="firstNameValue" />
        <label (click)="searchByFirstName()">Search</label>
      </div>

      <!-- Search Recod by Individual Customer Last Name -->

      <div class="text-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Last Name" [(ngModel)]="lastNameValue" />
        <label (click)="searchByLastName()">Search</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In backend I call the api and fetch all the matching records and display them in a mat-table.

I was wondering how can I concat first name and last name and then search for matching records?
Can I implement it on FrontEnd or I need to ask backend team to make an API which takes two arguments and then search for records.

Comment: Couldn't you search by first name and then loop through the results to see if any matches the last name?

Answer (score 0):

You've set the `ngModel` for each input value in the HTML template, so to `concat` for the REST call, you can do this on the component:

```js
// app.component.ts

searchByFullName() {
  this.svc.filterFunction(this.firstNameValue + ' ' + this.lastNameValue).subscribe(response => {
    // update the table
  });
}
```

You'll have to update the `svc` call with the correct function and update the table update logic. You'll also have to specify how you want the name concatenated together; I just added a space between them in the above example.